# QT/QML, How to define code behind for QML Form

Tags: qt, qml

I know , that is an simple question.How can I create c++ side of a QML form like C#.İs there an option to seperate Design and code side

Comment: Inside QtCreator create `Qt Quick application` project and check `with ui.qml file`. I really don't understand what `c++ side` you are talking about. If you work with QML think QML, not C#.

Comment: This is possible in QT Form Application.I mean there is an Form Widget and code behind (c++ class).I want to catch Form isloaded , isclosed etc...